# GPU on yocto rocko - kernel 4.14

Tags: kernel, yocto, imx6

I am working on IMX6QP on yocto rocko by [karo](https://www.karo-electronics.de/1262.html) and 4.14.24 kernel.
I built Qt5.9.6.

Can I use the GPU with this kernel ?

When I try to run "Qt5_CinematicExperience --platform eglfs" the system try to open "/usr/lib/dri/etnaviv_dri.so" and this file not exists. In this folder i only have "swrast_dri.so".
How can I build the etnaviv driver?

I cannot include meta-freescale in my yocto. Where can I build the vivante driver?

Thanks in advance,

rBeal

Comment: Im having exact the same problem. The vivante-drivers are long broken. The key is to build mesa with etnaviv support. I've already figured out to enable `CONFIG_DRM_ETNAVIV=y` in the Kernel and to add `libdrm-etnaviv`to the image. But I'm still missing `etnaviv_dri.so`.

Comment: Solved on this thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041843/use-vivante-gpu-on-imx6-with-4-14-kernel